# Replace 3rd element with regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting an array like below after doing the matches.
[ '10 am', '5 pm', 'by appointment only' ]
I would like to append text **to** only for time and return in this format.

"10 am to 5 pm by appointment only"

But when I join like below

```
[ '10 am', '5 pm', 'by appointment only' ].join( 'to' );
```

I am getting result as

> "10 am to 5 pm to by appointment only"

So with the help of regular expression is there a way to to remove **'to'** only from 3rd element of array so that when joining it won't append **'to '** again.

Comment: I guess you should overthink your methods instead of going a hacky route

Comment: `myArray[0] + ' to ' + myArray[1] + ' ' + myArray[2]`?

Comment: Why not just insert it between the two first elements to begin with? If you don't need this for "dynamic" arrays, but only for ones that always have these three elements - then do `data[0] + ' to ' + data[1] + ' ' + data[2]` ...?

Answer (score 3):

If this would be your only use case (ie. the format of the strings is always like this), you can code it explicitly:

```
const [start,end,describe] = [ '10 am', '5 pm', 'by appointment only' ];
const finalText = `${start} to ${end} ${describe}`;
console.log(finalText)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const arr1 = ['10 am', '5 pm', 'by appointment only']
const arr2 = ['By Appointment:', '10 am', '5 pm']
const getFormattedAppoiment = arr => {
  const { appointment, startEnd } = arr.reduce(
    (a, c, i) => {
      if (/\d/.test(c)) {
        a.startEnd.push(c)
      } else {
        a.appointment.text = c
        a.appointment.position = i
      }
      return a
    },
    {
      startEnd: [], 
      appointment: { 
        text: '',
        position: 0,
      },
    }
  )
  const startEndText = startEnd.join(' to ')

  return appointment.position === 0
    ? `${appointment.text} ${startEndText}`
    : `${startEndText} ${appointment.text}`
}

console.log(getFormattedAppoiment(arr1))
console.log(getFormattedAppoiment(arr2))
```

Comment: Actually I am getting 2 different formats like below.
1) const arr = ['10 am', '5 pm', 'by appointment only'] or 
2) const arr = ['By Appointment : ', '10 am', '5 pm']
So in first case, the result should be '10 am to 5 pm by appointment only'


For second case, the result should be 'By Appointment : 10 am to 5 pm '

Comment: Basically we are removing unwanted 'to' string

Comment: @rubyist edited answer to handle appointment result text at position 0 or 2